# Recurring error using lmer() function for a linear mixed-effects model

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I attempted to construct a linear mixed effects model using `lmer` function from `lme4` package and I ran into a recurring error.  The model uses two fixed effects:

- `DBS_Electrode` (factor w/3 levels) and
- `PostOp_ICA` (continuous variable).

I use `(1 | Subject)` as a random effect term in which `Subject` is a factor of 38 levels (38 total subjects). Below is the line of code I attempted to run:

```
LMM.DBS <- lmer(Distal_Lead_Migration ~ DBS_Electrode + PostOp_ICA + (1 | Subject), data = DBS)
```

I recieved the following error:

> Number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations.

I would appreciate any help, I have tried to navigate this issue myself and have been unsuccessful.

Comment: could you post some reproducible example? E.g. not only the line of your code but some piece of data. It should greately increasy the probability of answer.

Answer (score 0):

Linear mixed effect model supposes that there is less subjects than observations so it throws an if it is not the case.

> You can think of this formula as telling your model that it should
>   expect that there’s going to be multiple responses per subject, and
>   these responses will depend on each subject’s baseline level.

Please consult [A very basic tutorial for performing linear mixed effects analyses by B. Winter, p. 4](http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial2.pdf).

In your case you should increase amount of observations per subject (> 1). Please see the simulation below:

```
library(lme4)
set.seed(123)
n <- 38
DBS_Electrode <- factor(sample(LETTERS[1:3], n, replace = TRUE))

Distal_Lead_Migration <- 10 * abs(rnorm(n))    # Distal_Lead_Migration in cm
PostOp_ICA <- 5 * abs(rnorm(n))

# amount of observations equals to amout of subjects
Subject <- paste0("X", 1:n)
DBS <- data.frame(DBS_Electrode, PostOp_ICA, Subject, Distal_Lead_Migration)
model <- lmer(Distal_Lead_Migration ~ DBS_Electrode + PostOp_ICA + (1|Subject), data = DBS)
# Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations


# amount of observations more than amout of subjects
Subject <- c(paste0("X", 1:36), "X1", "X37")
DBS <- data.frame(DBS_Electrode, PostOp_ICA, Subject, Distal_Lead_Migration)
model <- lmer(Distal_Lead_Migration ~ DBS_Electrode + PostOp_ICA + (1|Subject), data = DBS)
summary(model)
```

Output:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Distal_Lead_Migration ~ DBS_Electrode + PostOp_ICA + (1 | Subject)
   Data: DBS

REML criterion at convergence: 224.5

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.24605 -0.73780 -0.07638  0.64381  2.53914 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 Subject  (Intercept) 2.484e-14 1.576e-07
 Residual             2.953e+01 5.434e+00
Number of obs: 38, groups:  Subject, 37

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)     7.82514    2.38387   3.283
DBS_ElectrodeB  0.22884    2.50947   0.091
DBS_ElectrodeC -0.60940    2.21970  -0.275
PostOp_ICA     -0.08473    0.36765  -0.230

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) DBS_EB DBS_EC
DBS_ElctrdB -0.718              
DBS_ElctrdC -0.710  0.601       
PostOp_ICA  -0.693  0.324  0.219
```